# jQuery to Javascript code for document.ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working to build a confetti effect with pure JavaScript. right now i am getting nan error when i try to convert the following code with DOMContentlocaded method:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    console.log("Inside the DOMCONTENT LOADED FUNCTION")
      SetGlobals();
      //InitializeButton();
      InitializeConfetti();

      window.resize = function (event) {
          W = window.innerWidth;
          H = window.innerHeight;
          canvas.width = W;
          canvas.height = H;
      };
      window.setTimeout(DeactivateConfetti, 4000000);
  });
```

Here's the fiddle link: [Confetti Link](https://jsfiddle.net/zo4am34e/)

Comment: I have followed this article too however, for unknown reason this code is not working

Comment: if you can be a bit more clear on what the unknown reason is (in your question) i will consider reopening if it makes it not a duplicate.